# How do I shrink a Word document before printing?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft Word document that was generated from a report server.  The document is usually generated to Excel, so it's a series of columns across the page.  It won't fit on an 8.5.x11 page without wrapping, even if the document is in landscape mode.

In order to print the document I'd like to shrink it before printing.  Not resize the fonts or anything like that, but actually zoom out so the columns all fit.  It'll be a bit of a squint to read it but the client is ok with that.

Does anyone know how best to go about doing this in Word 2003 or 2007?

Answer (score 3):

If you can still generate the file to open in Excel you can actually do this in Excel.  Go into Page Setup and either choose `Adjust To` or `Fit To` on the Page tab.  Enter the parameters for whichever setting you choose.

[image]